# xsl: match newly created element from another xsl file

Tags: xml, xslt

I have created an XSL file that contains common transforms to be performed on xml. This file will be included in several other XSL files which will then add more templates on top of these common rules. The problem I have is, I want to match an element that will be created by a template in common, but there is no guarentee it will be created by the time the more specific xsl need to match it. xsl:

**common-stylesheet.xsl**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns="http://www.standards.org/Intake"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"  version="2.0"> <!-- xs namespace allows typed functions and parameters -->
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" /> 

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*|text()|comment()|processing-instruction()">
    <xsl:copy />
</xsl:template>

<!-- remove root -->
<xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="OccurrenceData">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:element name="custom_Occurrence">
            <!-- template adds 2 more elements to custom_Occurrence, omitted for brevity -->
            <xsl:call-template name="createOccurrenceContent" />
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
<!-- rest of stylesheet -->
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**first-specific-stylesheet.xsl**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
<xsl:import href="common-stylesheet.xsl" />
<xsl:template match="custom_Occurrence">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:element name="custom_TestElement"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
<!-- rest of stylesheet -->
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am sending the following input xml through first-specific-stylesheet:

**input.xml**

```
<Request>
    <RequestData>
        <Occurrence>
            <OccurrenceCd>EJ104</OccurrenceCd>
            <!-- more children -->
        </Occurrence>
        <!-- rest of input-->
    </RequestData>
</Request>
```

And the outcome should look like the following:

**desired-output.xml**

```
<RequestData>
    <Occurrence>
        <OccurrenceCd>EJ104</Occurrence>
        <custom_Occurrence>
            <custom_TestElement />
        </custom_Occurrence>
        <!--more children -->
    </Occurrence>
    <!-- rest of output -->
</RequestData>
```

At the minute, the common templates are ran and they work as expected, but `<custom_TestElement>` is missing from `<custom_Occurrence>`.Is there a way to include the common file to them ore specific xsl file, and ensure that the common file templates are ran before the more specific file starts to match the new elements? Is that possible in one file, or would I have to split the transforms into their own steps, i.e. run the common transform first, then pipe the xml into the more specific xml?

Note: I am using the `<xsl:element name="{local-name()}">` and the tweaked identity transform with extra template format as the source xml doesn't have a namespace, and I am applying one in the common xsl; without these, the namespace was applied to every element, either with a blank value or with the full value. Also, I am using Saxon-HE v9.7.0-8 for the transforms

EDIT: I would be unable to move the creation of custom_OCCurrence to the more specific stylesheets; that element block and its contents are shared amongst all specific stylesheets, with each one adding a different element(s) and value(s) to that element "block" depending on which one is used

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use a variable as in

```
<xsl:variable name="temp">
        <xsl:element name="custom_Occurrence">
            <!-- template adds 2 more elements to custom_Occurrence, omitted for brevity -->
            <xsl:call-template name="createOccurrenceContent" />
        </xsl:element>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:apply-templates select="$temp/node()"/>
```

if you want to apply a template to a node your XSLT creates.

Comment: Im not sure I understand. So create a variable in common and call it in common?

Comment: Instead of the `<xsl:element name="custom_Occurrence">...</xsl:element>` you need to put the code I have shown in the answer so that the element is first created and then processed, there is no magic of having newly created nodes being matched by templates, so you either need to use a variable or you indeed need to processing steps.

Comment: This left out the custom_Occurrence element altogether, assuming I've followed this approach correctly, are you able to expand the code snippet for context?